# Is there any free semantically correct HTML Form code (HTML+CSS) maker, generator?

Tags: css, xhtml

Is there any free semantically correct HTML Form code (HTML+CSS) maker, generator?

With HTML and CSS both.

Comment: You probably mean "syntactically correct", not "semantically correct", right?

Answer (score 1):

You can build a form in Wufoo, apply a theme and then export it as html + css

http://wufoo.com

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any decent HTML form generators - all the generators host the actual form itself (like Wufoo). I did however find a couple of good examples of HTML form markups:

1. http://www.gethifi.com/blog/html-forms-the-right-ways
2. http://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/example-form-markup/

Hope this helps =)